# Best way to parse unknown XML fom web service

Tags: objective-c, web-services, wsdl, xml-parsing

I am working on a project where I required to parse XML response coming from web service. I don't know anything about the structure of response. I am given XML elements to gather data for, and the data is relational so elements represents columns in relational table.

I tried the WSDL approach where I can parse for method name and its response type. Based on that I can parse with NSXMLParser. The problem was I didn't find any WSDL parser which does this for me.

Any suggestions?!

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: one format only? or dynamic and changing all the time?

Comment: web service url and coumn names are provided by user, so I have to take web service url, call it, get response and parse it and create relational table where columns(elements or attributes in XML file) are specified by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use this OpenSource library on [GitHub](https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary) 
It will allow you to turn the `XML` string into an NSDictionary which you can the use dynamically.

Comment: Hey Amit, Thanks for the response !!! I would like to try it but the problem is sometimes the xml file can be too large to fit in memory...I have to see if it can just return the structure without data.....

Comment: If your files are very large, I'd look at `libxml2`. It can handle walking through very large files, and has better performance than `NSXMLParser`. There isn't many other options other than walking through it yourself. Maybe create an `NSMutableArray` of all the tags that you need, and build a structure like that.

Comment: The main problem is determining the structure of the response because,for example, some tags may be present in one row (record) but missing in some other row meaning no value for that tag.So I cannot simply keep putting values in respective arrays. So only way I determine the structure is using output type in WSDL...

Comment: What about just rebuilding the XML without the data using Arrays? That way it will still be dynamic. You would just essentially loading the entire structure into memory.

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for the responses!!! I just extracted the set of elements based on nesting level of it.I record relative nesting levels of elements by scanning xml file. The I start scanning for values. Based on when nesting level goes beyond the limits of nesting levels for the elements, I decide when to start and stop a set of values(i.e. a row).